# LocalStorage - laço for removendo índice errado

Tags: javascript, localstorage

estou criando um armazenamento de favoritos em localStorage com JS, porém quando clico em "deletar" na maioria das vezes ele não remove o item correto, as vezes até remove porém deleta outros itens também, segue o HTML e o JS:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Site Bookmarker</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body onload="fetchBookmarks()">

    <div class="container">
      <div class="header clearfix">
        <nav>

        </nav>
        <h3 class="text-muted">Bookmarker</h3>
      </div>

      <div class="jumbotron">
        <h2>Bookmark Your Favorite Sites</h2>
        <form id="myForm">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Site Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="siteName" placeholder="Website Name">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Site URL</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="siteUrl" placeholder="Website URL">
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>

      <div class="row marketing">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <div id="bookmarksResults"></div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <footer class="footer">
        <p>&copy; 2016 Bookmarker, Inc.</p>
      </footer>

    </div> <!-- /container -->

    <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"
    integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
// Listen for form submit
document.getElementById('myForm').addEventListener('submit', saveBookmark);

// Save Bookmark
function saveBookmark(e){
  // Get form values
  var siteName =document.getElementById('siteName').value;
  var siteUrl =document.getElementById('siteUrl').value;

  if(!validateForm(siteName, siteUrl)){
    return false;
  }

  var bookmark = {
    name: siteName,
    url: siteUrl
  }

  /*
    // Local Storage Test
    localStorage.setItem('test', 'Hello World');
    console.log(localStorage.getItem('test'));
    localStorage.removeItem('test');
    console.log(localStorage.getItem('test'));
  */

  // Test if bookmarks is null
  if(localStorage.getItem('bookmarks') === null){
    // Init array
    var bookmarks = [];
    // Add to array
    bookmarks.push(bookmark);
    // Set to localStorage
    localStorage.setItem('bookmarks', JSON.stringify(bookmarks));
  } else {
    // Get bookmarks from localStorage
    var bookmarks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('bookmarks'));
    // Add bookmark to array
    bookmarks.push(bookmark);
    // Re-set back to localStorage
    localStorage.setItem('bookmarks', JSON.stringify(bookmarks));
  }

  // Clear form
  document.getElementById('myForm').reset();

  // Re-fetch bookmarks
  fetchBookmarks();

  // Prevent form from submitting
  e.preventDefault();
}

// Delete bookmark
function deleteBookmark(url){
  // Get bookmarks from localStorage
  var bookmarks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('bookmarks'));
  // Loop through the bookmarks
  for(var i =0;i < bookmarks.length;i++){
    if(bookmarks[i].url == url){
      // Remove from array
      bookmarks.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }
  // Re-set back to localStorage
  localStorage.setItem('bookmarks', JSON.stringify(bookmarks));

  // Re-fetch bookmarks
  fetchBookmarks();
}

// Fetch bookmarks
function fetchBookmarks(){
  // Get bookmarks from localStorage
  var bookmarks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('bookmarks'));
  // Get output id
  var bookmarksResults = document.getElementById('bookmarksResults');

  // Build output
  bookmarksResults.innerHTML = '';
  for(var i = 0; i < bookmarks.length; i++){
    var name = bookmarks[i].name;
    var url = bookmarks[i].url;

    bookmarksResults.innerHTML += '<div class="well">'+
                                  '<h3>'+name+
                                  ' <a class="btn btn-default" target="_blank" href="'+addhttp(url)+'">Visit</a> ' +
                                  ' <a onclick="deleteBookmark(\''+url+'\')" class="btn btn-danger" href="#">Delete</a> ' +
                                  '</h3>'+
                                  '</div>';
  }
}

// Validate Form
function validateForm(siteName, siteUrl){
  if(!siteName || !siteUrl){
    alert('Please fill in the form');
    return false;
  }

  var expression = /[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?/gi;
  var regex = new RegExp(expression);

  if(!siteUrl.match(regex)){
    alert('Please use a valid URL');
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}

function addhttp(url) {
  if (!/^(?:f|ht)tps?\:\/\//.test(url)) {
      url = "http://" + url;
  }
  return url;
}
```

Comment: Já tentou colocando um `break` no final desse `if(bookmarks[i].url == url){` que está dentro do laço `for`? É porque se ele achou o índice, não faz mais sentido continuar o laço, porque irá alterar o `.length` do `bookmarks` com o `.splice`. Não testei, mas pode ser isso o problema.

Answer (score -3):

Dentro da sua função `deleteBookmark` substitua o laço de repetição por uma High Order Function(HOF) chamada Filter().

Essa HOF lhe retornará uma nova array contendo apenas os resultados `true` do teste lógico que você criar.

Exemplo: `bookmarks = bookmarks.filter(({ url: urlSalva }) => urlSalva !== url );`

- Basicamente você está dizendo que o novo valor da variável `bookmarks` é ela mesmo filtrada contendo apenas o itens onde a chave `url` do objeto é diferente da `url` recebida por parâmetro em `deleteBookmark`.

Essa única linha de código vai substituir tudo que o seu `for` está fazendo de forma mais segura e confiável.

Recomendo a leitura para entender o que são [High Order Functions](https://www.alura.com.br/artigos/high-order-functions?gclid=Cj0KCQjws4aKBhDPARIsAIWH0JVrH4mAP4bIZ9-0EL1fYJ7L9KMn7fhKGVBboMBUavN0pbCvbbIUAyAaAkz0EALw_wcB).

Recomendo a leitura para entender como utilizar o [Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Obs.: No exemplo usei um *alias* para diferenciar a `url` do objeto salvo na sua array da `url` recebida por parâmetro que você quer excluir.

Aqui você pode ler mais sobre [desestruturação de objetos javascript](https://www.alura.com.br/artigos/es6-desestruturando-objetos?gclid=Cj0KCQjws4aKBhDPARIsAIWH0JVeTMLWd42p79z46uP6VF6su_oIEjfiDdxZV7zeYsOgBwSJ7p6aaO4aAlmEEALw_wcB).